# how to loop through gridview using jquery and check if any checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview

I am developing jquery based application. I have one asp.net gridview with checkboxes in every row. I want to check if any of the checkboxes checked or not. I am looping through gridview rows and checking any checkbox is checked or not as below.

```
var ResultArrayFirst = [];
        $('#<%= gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> input[type="hidden"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true))
            {
                ResultArrayFirst.push($(this).val());
            }

        });
        alert(ResultArrayFirst);
```

My above code does not works. As soon as above code is executed, all checkboxes will check. I am not sure what i Am missing here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if a checkbox is checked, use this:

```
if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
   // Do your stuff
}
```

So, change your code like this:

```
if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'))
{
   ResultArrayFirst.push($(this).val());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:checked` selector of jquery

```
 $('#<%= gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> input[type="hidden"]').each(function () {
     if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked"))
     {
         ResultArrayFirst.push($(this).val());
     }

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give a class to checkbox as example `chk` and than use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) instead of each loop it will get items in an array please find below single line of code to achieve

```
var selected =  $(".chk:checked").map(function(i,el){return el.value;}).get();
```

As well as if you wants to just check if any check boxes is checked or not you can do as below it will return a `bool` value

```
$(".chk").is(":checked")
```